# Is there a Ruby framework similar to the Flash Player capabilities?

Tags: ruby, flash, actionscript-3, media, processing

Is there an open source Ruby framework that allows working with multimedia (video, sound, etc) similar to Flash, including Display Object hierarchy, that is not targeted for video games?

I'm looking for something between Ruby/Processing with a more object oriented API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at [Ruby-Processing](https://github.com/jashkenas/ruby-processing/wiki) that runs on jruby.

Comment: I already did, as I mention in my question, I'm looking for something that can manage a display list in an OO way.